# How to use image URL in custom Views?

Tags: views, 8

I use the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module for my custom Views. The Views settings look like so:

#### Setting field:

[image: Setting field]

#### Setting custom text:

[image]

This is the result I get:

[image]

#### Inspect html

```
<div class="views-field views-field-nothing"><span class="field-content">
<div>
http://example.com/sites/default/files/color-placeholder/team-1.jpg
)"&gt;
  <ul class="social-team"><li><a class="fa fa-facebook" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="fa fa-instagram" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="fa fa-twitter" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="fa fa-github" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
  <a href="/md8/features/kate-benke" hreflang="en">Kate Benke</a>
  Back-End Developer
</div>
</span></div>
```

How should I correct my config to use mage URL?

Note: I don't want override template.

Answer (score 2):

Views field strips out `<div style="..">` tag. To add background image you need to follow below steps:

1. Add global custom field into view header and put below code.

> ```
> <style type="text/css">
>     .background-img { 
>       background: url('{{ field_photo_team }}'); 
>     }  
> </style>
> ```

2. Now assign ***background-img*** class to  **Global :Custom text** field like

.

```
<div class="background-img">
{{ field_social }}
{{ title}}
{{ field_profession_team }}
</div>
```

> Note: Use Global Text Area in view header and select an input filter
>   where html tags aren't limited i.e. full html text format

Comment: Sorry, i config same way, but return same result. Do you try it?

Comment: I have just modified the answer, please try out.

Comment: @John did you try adding the quotes `' '` wrapping the url?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, he tried quotes ' ', but no luck. Hence I have modified the answer.